# Does Posteo.de support Sieve/Managesieve protocol?

Tags: github, email

Posteo.de offers filters which can be configured through the web UI. This function is however lacking function of the full set of sieve features which I'd get from filters defined through a Sievemanager, like the Sieve Thunderbird add-on.

[Their FAQ doesn't mention it](https://posteo.de/en/help?search=sieve), I'm however almost certain that I already used it in the past. Maybe it was removed or hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are looking for this plugin which adds the ability for users to manage their sieve mail filter rules: **[SieveRules-Managesieve](https://github.com/posteo/Roundcube-Plugin-SieveRules-Managesieve)**

If so, then answer you your question is yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So, I can only configure the sieve filters through a roundcube instance which I have to set up and in which I'm installing the reference plugin? If sieve is supported by the server shouldn't I be able to connect with any managesieve client?

Comment: as far as I know, it's supported only indirectly via plugin+roundcube

Comment: I got a reply from posteo.de support stateing that they don't support external interfaces and that configuration ought to be done through filters in the Web UI.